# PlacesService's text search not consistent with Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

We're seeing an issue where the PlacesService's textSearch is not returning any results for the "Strood Station Car Park, Rochester", whereas the Autocomplete is. I've created this JS Fiddle that shows the demonstrates this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/anero/b5jh56gy/6/

Is there a way to have a consistent result set for both API calls?

```
var client = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($("#google-attributions")[0]);
var query = "Strood Station Car Park, Rochester";
var textSearchRequest = {
    query: query
};

client.textSearch(textSearchRequest, function (response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && response.length > 0) {
        alert('Found place!');
    } else {
        alert('Did not find place!');
    }
});
```